# Reading new data from a constantly updating file in Java

Tags: java, file, io, stream

I have a log file which is constantly updated with new lines of data. I need to get new added data in java as soon as it's written. For now my solution is:

```
public static void readNonStop(String filename, boolean goToEnd, FileReadCallback readCallback) {
    if(readCallback == null) {
        return;
    }
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
        try {
            String line = br.readLine();
            int lineNumber = 0;

            if(goToEnd) {
                while(br.readLine() != null) {}
            }

            while (true) {
                if(line != null) {
                    readCallback.onRead(lineNumber++, line);
                } else {
                    Thread.sleep(1);
                }
                line = br.readLine();
            }
        } finally {
            br.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But I have a feeling that there should be a better way. I don't like the idea of a constant running loop with a "sleep" inside and would prefer some sort of an event driven approach.

If I rely on FileSystem events to reopen the file each time it is modified, it introduces a delay.

What is the correct way of doing it for this situation?

Comment: Consider [Tailer](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/input/Tailer.html) class from Apache Commons.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. I hope you get some good reviews, and I hope to see more of your contributions here in future!

Comment: @vnp, wow, looks like what I need. While a bit more robust, `Tailer` uses the same logic as my code, it reads in a loop with a `Thread.sleep` delay. But it feels good to confirm that I had the right idea, thanks! @Zeta, thank you!

Comment: Maybe there is a "native" solution too: https://dzone.com/articles/how-watch-file-system-changes or https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html

Comment: `WatcherService` introduces a delay up to 6 seconds in my tests, so unfortunately it is not an option. Looks like I will go with a looped read.

Comment: Aren’t you missing `lineNumber++;` in your `goToEnd` while loop?

Comment: @AJNeufeld, sorry, the line number is not relevant anymore. I've updated my code.

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Java `WatchService` as described [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html). You said that `WatchService` is too slow for you. There are other people who have had that problem and resolved it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9588737/is-java-7-watchservice-slow-for-anyone-else[in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9588737/is-java-7-watchservice-slow-for-anyone-else).

On a side note, consider using `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` rather than `Thread.sleep`. The former will recreate threads if they are killed by an exception, has the potential to reuse threads in a pool, and has other potential advantages.

Answer (score 1):

#### `try`-with-resources

`BufferedReader` implements [`AutoCloseable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html), so instead of

> ```
>     try {
>         BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
>         try {
> ```

You can say

```
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename))) {
```

and then get rid of your `finally` block.

> ```
>         } finally {
>             br.close();
>         }
> ```

Also, this should allow you to merge the two `try` statements into one, as the resource declaration is inside the scope of the `try` if it throws an exception.

#### Odd behavior

> ```
>             String line = br.readLine();
>             int lineNumber = 0;
> ```

So you read the first line of the file.  Then, if a Boolean is true, you skip all the other lines of the file without counting them (even though you just declared a variable to count them).  Then you process the first line of the file.  Why not

```
        if (goToEnd) {
            while (br.readLine() != null) {}
        }

        // we only want to count lines past the current end of file
        int lineNumber = 0;
        while (true) {
            String line = br.readline();
            while (line == null) {
                Thread.sleep(1);
                line = br.readLine();
            }

            readCallback.onRead(lineNumber++, line);
        }
```

Now it's clearer that `lineNumber` has nothing to do with the part before the end of the current file.  And we don't process the first line of the file and then a much later line.  Each `line` lasts only one iteration of the loop.

If the condition is false, a `while` acts just like an `if`.  But if the condition is true, we can stay in the loop.

If this is not the behavior that you want, please add comments to your code explaining why.  E.g. "We always need to read the first line of the file as line number 0, even if we skip the rest of the existing lines.  This is because the first line has the column headers."

Comment: Thanks for your answer, though lineNumber is not relevant anymore.